# Using a third-party service to populate and search WordPress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I use a third-party service to populate posts into my WordPress website.  Much of the information that comes from the service is stored as WordPress post properties (title, content, images, etc), but some of it is stored as post metadata (service's unique identifiers for each post and other metadata).  The services offers a radius search to find posts that match within a given location, and returns the IDs for the posts that match.  My goal is to take these IDs and return a paginated result set from the WP posts so that everything is formatted like any other search page in the WP site.  I have a working implementation of this, but it is very slow, and am looking for advice on how to speed it up, or different approaches to accomplish my goal.

My current implementation does a paginated loop for all of the matching posts on the service (this could return 10 results or 1000 results).  Then I take the IDs from that result set and pass them into a WP Query to limit the request by a meta value of the IDs.  The request gets slower the larger the data set from the service is.  I am doing it this way to allow me to take advantage of WP's pagination.  If I were to just return a single page in the paginated results, WordPress wouldn't know that there were more results to paginate through.  Any advice or recommendations on how to make this process more performant would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code that I have so far.  It currently works, but as mentioned, the larger the dataset from the service, the longer the request takes:

```html
<?php

class Search {
    const SEARCH_PREFIX = 'test';
    protected static $api_params_whitelist = [
        'search',
        'near_zip',
        'near_city',
        'radius',
        'featured_only',
        'currently_listed_only',
        'registrable_only',
        'page',
        'per_page',
        'sort'
    ];

    public static function radius_search($query) {
        $field_prefix = Search::SEARCH_PREFIX;
        $search = $query->get($field_prefix . 'term');
        $location = $query->get($field_prefix . 'location');
        $radius = $query->get($field_prefix . 'radius');
        
        if (
            $query->is_main_query()
            && (strlen($location) > 0)
        ) {
            // Lookup result IDs for radius.
            if ($resultIds = self::get_result_ids($search, $location, $radius)) {
                $query->set( 'meta_query',  array(
                    // Search for the result id stored in `post_meta`.
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'id',
                        'value'   => $resultIds,
                        'compare' => 'IN',
                    ),
                ) );
            } else {
                // Force no results
                $query->set( 'post__in', array(0) );
            }
        } elseif ( strlen( $search ) > 0 ) {
            // Fallback to standard WP search w/o radius search
            $query->set( 's', $search );
        }
    }

    public static function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ) {
        $field_prefix = Search::SEARCH_PREFIX;

        $query_variables = [
            $field_prefix . 'term',
            $field_prefix . 'location',
            $field_prefix . 'radius'
        ];

        foreach ($query_variables as $var) {
            $vars[] = $var;
        }
        
        return $vars;
    }

    private static function get_api_handler() {
        $credentials = Synchronize::get_credentials();

        if( !isset( $credentials['subdomain'] ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        $api = new \My_Api( $credentials['subdomain'] );
        $api->setTimeoutInSeconds( 10 );

        return $api;
    }

    private static function get_result_ids($search, $location, $radius) {
        $api = self::get_api_handler();

        $page = 1;
        $per_page = 60;
        $results = [];

        $params = $_GET;
        $params['per_page'] = $per_page;

        $query_params = $api->getQueryParams( $params, Search::SEARCH_PREFIX, self::$api_params_whitelist );

        do {
            $query_params['page'] = $page;
            $query_params['fields'] = [
                'id'
            ];

            $results = $api->get( '/search', $query_params );
            $resultCount = count($results);

            if ($results && $resultCount > 0) {
                $results = array_merge($results, $results);
            }
            $page++;
        } while ($results && $resultCount > 0);
        
        if (count($results)) {
            return array_column($results, 'id');
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```